# How can I redirect any request with matching URL except a specific exact string?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-extension

I'm trying to create a regex filter on mv3 declarativeNetRequest rule but it keep giving me this error

> Rule with id 1 specifies an incorrect value for the "regexFilter" key.

This is the regex I used

```
^https:\/\/example\.com\/js\/script\.js(\?(?!\bext\b)[^&=]+(=[^&=]*)*)?$
```

This should match `https://example.com/js/script.js?<anything>`
but should fail on exactly `https://example.com/js/script.js?ext`

The regex seems to be ES regex compliant and works just fine when I test it.

Comment: As the documentation says RE2 syntax used by this API doesn't support `?!`. You'll have to use two rules, one blocking everything and the other one is an exception with a higher priority.